# How do I make a pointer inside a struct point to the same string pointed by another pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I have the following code:

```c
struct el{      
    char *line;
    struct el *next;
};
```

```c
struct el *abc, def;
char *p1;
char buffer[100];
```

```c
abc = &def;
gets(buffer);
p1 = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1 );
strcpy( p1, buffer);
```

How can I make `line` point to the same string pointed by `p1` without allocating the same string twice? Is it enough to write:

```
 abc->line = p1;
```

Or do I also need to free the area pointed by `p1`?

Comment: 1) don't use `gets` 2) `sizeof(strlen(buffer))` is completely wrong

Comment: `abc->line = p1` doesn't create a copy. Freeing p1 frees the other pointer too (same addresses)

Comment: Is there a faster function than gets ?

Comment: Use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Comment: @Andrea it is not a matter of speed. It is just it is unsafe, as it doesn't perform any check on the size of the input (in your case, since `buffer` has size 100, by sending in input more than 100 chars will make gets write out of bounds, and that will probably crash your program).

Comment: Ok thank you, i will change it immediately

Comment: Expanding the second advice from @Jean, with `sizeof(strlen(buffer))` you are calculating the size (`sizeof`) of the value returned by strlen, that will be `sizeof (size_t)` whatever the length of the string contained in buffer is. So you will always get 8 (or 4, depending to your platform). Just use `malloc (strlen (buffer) + 1)`

Comment: `abc->line = p1;` does exactly what you think it does. It takes the value in p1 (which is an address) and saves that same value into abc->line. Now abc->line and p1 store the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sense something smelly... Namely, that all your variables seem to be local variables (on the stack) that cease to exist when your function returns.

So would your function end with

```
return abc;
```

then you loose everything because you said `abc= &def;` and `def` is also a local variable. So yes, you can simply do `abc->line= p1;` but after the return you have lost `abc` (which points to `def` which was a stack variable that then no longer exists) and hence you have also lost `abc->line` and so you have a memory leak.

So you should expand the code you show us for us to be able to say "Yes you can do that".

The following is an example of a function that is wrong:

```
struct el{
    char *line;
    struct el *next;
};

struct el *example(void)
{
    struct el *abc, def;    // def is a local variable
    char *p1;
    char buffer[100];
        
    abc = &def;
    gets(buffer);
    p1 = malloc( strlen(buffer) + 1 );
    strcpy( p1, buffer);
    
    abc->line= p1;
    return abc;             // def won't exist anymore after the function returns
}
```

To fix this error, you should also do `abc= malloc(sizeof(struct el));` or pass a pointer variable to the function, for example:

```
void example2(struct el *abc)
{
    char *p1;
    // ...
    abc->line= p1;
 }
```

and call as for example:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct el pqr = {0};
    example2(&pqr);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So do i need to use pointers to pointers? @Paul Ogilvie

Comment: @Andrea - No, you do not _need_ to use double pointers to update values of a struct instance.  That is not the main message Paul is providing here.  He is referring to the fact that you have created local, automatic variables within an area of temporary lifespan.  The stack locations(addresses)  created while execution flow is within the function will cease to exist upon leaving.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie So let's say that struct el *abc is a parameter passed to the function, when i write abc->line = p1, will this assignment remain also after the return?

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie I mean, will abc->line still point to the area allocated inside the function (the one pointed by p1)?

Comment: If the function signature would be for example `void f(struct el *abc)` then `abc->line= p1;` is correct. That is because `abc` no longer points to a local variable.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make `line` point to the same string pointed by `p1` without allocating the same string twice? Is it enough to write:
>
> ```
> abc->line = p1;
> ```

Yes, you can do that.  `abc->line` will be pointing to the same memory address as `p1`.

> Or do I also need to free the area pointed by 'p1'?

No, you don't need to free both. You should either use:

```
free(abc->line);
```

or:

```
free(p1);
```

You only need one of them, as both pointers are pointing to the same memory address, when you free one you free both.

Note that by freeing `abc->line`, `p1` will become a dangling pointer, it will be pointing no nothing meaningful.

[Recommended read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/6865932) regarding `gets`.

Answer (score 1):

First, using [gets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)  is not recommended.  A good replacement is [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

*How can I make 'line' point to the same string pointed by 'p1' without allocating >the same string twice?*

Two pointers can both point to the same buffer simply by setting them to point to the address of the buffer.  Dynamic memory allocation is not necessary.
Given your code:

```
//the following are created in file global scope
struct el{
    char *line;
    struct el *next;
};

struct el *abc, def; 

char *p1;
char buffer[100];

//The following is performed in local scope within a function, using global variables created above.
p1 = &buffer[0];//assign address of buffer to pointer p1
//same for char *line:
abc->line = &buffer[0];//assign address of buffer to member *line

//both will now accept input using fgets()
fgets(p1, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
fgets(abc->line, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make `line` point to the same string pointed by `p1` without allocating the same string twice? Is it enough to write `abc->line = p1`?

Yes. `abc->line = p1;` is correct.

> Or do I also need to free the area pointed by `p1`?

No, not at all. In opposite, If you would do so, `line` would point to nowhere.

Note that `abc->line = p1;` only assigned the value of the memory address of the chunk allocated by `malloc()` from `p1` to the structure member `line`. They both are references to the **same ** memory allocated by `malloc()`.

---

Never ever use `gets()`. Reason why is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). It is also removed from the C standard since C11.